# How to add a dataset to the stacked bar in chart.js

Tags: chart.js

When I try to add a new data set to the stacked bar in `chart.js`, the data set can't be showed correctly (the red square should be filled in green).

Can someone help me? Thanks

Have a look on the image:
[image]

Following is my program:

https://codepen.io/stigersmile/pen/YRaebg

Comment: Where is the code ? Also have you tried debugging why is it happening ?

Comment: here is the code :https://codepen.io/stigersmile/pen/YRaebg

Comment: After looking at your code I see that you have set the backGroundColor of new dataset which is pushed on button click as `EBCCD1` which is red / light pink color then how can you expect the new bar to be green. Or you are trying to achieve something else?